# Why are the three variables (animal, vegetable, and mineral) still empty?

Tags: python, split, file-handling, python-3.10

I am using this program:

**splitter.py**

```
events = []
people = []
families = []

with open('AVM.py', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as toBeSplit: # opens the file for splitting

    for indexA,itemB in enumerate(toBeSplit): # get animals
        if itemB[1] == "Vegetable":
            aIndex = indexA
            animal = toBeSplit[0:aIndex] # adds them to a variable
            break
    

    for indexT,itemS in enumerate(toBeSplit): # gets vegetables
        if itemS[1] == "Mineral":
            vIndex = indexT
            vegetable = toBeSplit[aIndex:vIndex] # adds them to a variable
            mineral = toBeSplit[vIndex:] # rest is minerals
            break
```

Using this file:

**AVM.py**

```
data = [
    ["76534ytuieghfyo7g8t", "Animal", "Cheetah"],
    ["5r346tryiufuyfudguf", "Animal", "Lion"],
    ["435ytfhjgkghhgyutui", "Animal", "Bear"],
    ["uoiykgjhmvghdygyjj6", "Animal", "Cheetah"],
    ["783iuotywr78ifgudyf", "Vegetable", "Lettuce"],
    ["bmnfcvbhjdusyrewrt5", "Vegetable", "Zucchini"],
    ["5r6uyt4ity79uifigfh", "Vegetable", "Broccoli"],
    ["46e5r7tiuhbjkfsduig", "Mineral", "Quartz"],
    ["8935475youhgfhdchui", "Mineral", "Copper"]
]
```

I am trying to split the second file into the three types (animal, vegetable, mineral) so that later I can store them in separate files (I already have that part). But this is how I am splitting them, and the variables contain what I originally assigned them. How can I do this?

I think the if statements are coming out as false, but I don't understand why.

Comment: "I think the if statements is coming out to false" -> `print itemB[1]` and `print itemS[1]` and you don't need to guess

Comment: also there's nothing there that would actually parse the AVM.py file

Comment: that makes sense, but how would I? I want to be able to edit each separate file later.

Comment: Why not `import AVM` ? Then `vegetable = [x[2] for x in AVM.data if x[1] == "Vegetable"]`, etc.

Comment: Reading a .py file manually isn't a very good idea. Use a standard format like CSV or JSON or XML or whatever that has a parser available (if you can't just import the file and use the variable directly)

Comment: print `itemB[1]` in the loop and you'll see. You seem to expect that `itemB` is a list, but it is a string. And even if you somehow fix that: the second `for` loop will do nothing, because you're already at the end of the file after the first `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at solving this a few ways.

First, if you **really** want the data to be from a .py file, then you can simply import it. Though I recommend you use a json file and we will see that second.

```py
import avm

animals = []
vegetables = []
minerals = []

for row in avm.data:
    if row[1] == "Animal":
        animals.append(row[2])
    elif row[1] == "Vegetable":
        vegetables.append(row[2])
    elif row[1] == "Mineral":
        minerals.append(row[2])
    else:
        print(f"Unknow Category: {row[1]}")

print(f"Animals: {animals}")
print(f"Vegetables: {vegetables}")
print(f"Minerals: {minerals}")
```

That will give you:

```
Animals: ['Cheetah', 'Lion', 'Bear', 'Cheetah']
Vegetables: ['Lettuce', 'Zucchini', 'Broccoli']
Minerals: ['Quartz', 'Copper']
```

Let's change our data file to a json format:

**avm.json:**

```
[
    ["76534ytuieghfyo7g8t", "Animal", "Cheetah"],
    ["5r346tryiufuyfudguf", "Animal", "Lion"],
    ["435ytfhjgkghhgyutui", "Animal", "Bear"],
    ["uoiykgjhmvghdygyjj6", "Animal", "Cheetah"],
    ["783iuotywr78ifgudyf", "Vegetable", "Lettuce"],
    ["bmnfcvbhjdusyrewrt5", "Vegetable", "Zucchini"],
    ["5r6uyt4ity79uifigfh", "Vegetable", "Broccoli"],
    ["46e5r7tiuhbjkfsduig", "Mineral", "Quartz"],
    ["8935475youhgfhdchui", "Mineral", "Copper"]
]
```

Now we can get the same result via

```py
import json

animals = []
vegetables = []
minerals = []

with open("avm.json", "r") as data_in:
    data = json.load(data_in)

for row in data:
    if row[1] == "Animal":
        animals.append(row[2])
    elif row[1] == "Vegetable":
        vegetables.append(row[2])
    elif row[1] == "Mineral":
        minerals.append(row[2])
    else:
        print(f"Unknow Category: {row[1]}")

print(f"Animals: {animals}")
print(f"Vegetables: {vegetables}")
print(f"Minerals: {minerals}")
```

CSV files though provide a great deal of flexibility in that we can edit them with something like libreoffice.  If you can use one I would do that.

**avm.csv:**

```
"76534ytuieghfyo7g8t","Animal","Cheetah"
"5r346tryiufuyfudguf","Animal","Lion"
"435ytfhjgkghhgyutui","Animal","Bear"
"uoiykgjhmvghdygyjj6","Animal","Cheetah"
"783iuotywr78ifgudyf","Vegetable","Lettuce"
"bmnfcvbhjdusyrewrt5","Vegetable","Zucchini"
"5r6uyt4ity79uifigfh","Vegetable","Broccoli"
"46e5r7tiuhbjkfsduig","Mineral","Quartz"
"8935475youhgfhdchui","Mineral","Copper"
```

and

```py
import csv

animals = []
vegetables = []
minerals = []

with open("avm.csv", "r") as data_in:
    data = list(csv.reader(data_in))

for row in data:
    if row[1] == "Animal":
        animals.append(row[2])
    elif row[1] == "Vegetable":
        vegetables.append(row[2])
    elif row[1] == "Mineral":
        minerals.append(row[2])
    else:
        print(f"Unknow Category: {row[1]}")

print(f"Animals: {animals}")
print(f"Vegetables: {vegetables}")
print(f"Minerals: {minerals}")
```

should also give you the same result.

There are a bunch of other things I would recommend you look at in the future like determining the list to append to using a dictionary but I'll leave that to you.